# Await on join handle inside async?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I have a video player that plays a stream and should return whenever the video producer, the decoder or the renderer fails

```
pub async fn play_video(s: &MyStream) -> Result<(), Error> {
    tokio::select! {
        r = s.video_producer.run() => {
            Ok(r?)
        }
        r = s.decoder.run() => {
            Ok(r?)
        }
        //Renderer would go here, but it can't cause it's not `Send`
    }
}
```

However, since a `Renderer` usually has to be on a thread and not move to another, it's not `Send`, so it cannot be used inside an async call.

My solution was to spawn a thread and create the renderer inside the thread, so it never has to be moved from threads:

```
let renderer_join_handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {
    //...
})
```

I get a `JoinHandle<Result<(),RendererError>>` for which I can detect errors and return. However, it's not like the tokio select where it returns immediately. Is there a way to continuously poll this JoinHandle in the tokio select, thus async? Or is there a better solution that I'm not aware?

Basically I wanted the Renderer to be like the video producer and the decoder, and return its error on the tokio select.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `std::thread::spawn()`. Use [`tokio::task::spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html).

Alternatively, if the rendered *must* be on its own thread, you can create a oneshot async channel via [`tokio::sync::oneshot::channel()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/fn.channel.html). [`send()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/struct.Sender.html#method.send) the result to it from the rendered thread when it is finished, and receive from it by the `select!`.

Comment: Note that you *can* do `tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || joinhandle.join()).await` if you *have* to wait for a thread inside of an async function

Comment: @Finomnis True, but this is likely to be more expensive than using a channel.